# У меня проблема с удалением достижения для пользователя

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При попытке удаления achievement для user, я вместо удаления перехожу на страницу achievement show но я просто хочу стереть запись achievement

Моя view

```
<strong>Achievements:</strong>
<% @user.achievements.each do |achievement| %>
  <p>
    <%=link_to achievement.title, user_achievement_path(@user, achievement)%>
    <%=link_to "Delete", user_achievement_path(@user, achievement), :confirm => "Are you sure?", method: :delete%>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Модели

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :achievements

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
class Achievement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Контролер Achievement

```
class AchievementsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @achievement = @user.achievements.create(achievement_params)
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  def show
    @achievement = Achievement.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @achievement = Achievement.find(params[:id])
    @achievement.destroy
    redirect_to myprofile_path
  end

  private
  def achievement_params
    params.require(:achievement).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

myprofile_path это страница зарегистрированного пользователя.

Я действительно новичок в rails

Comment: В браузере в JS консоли есть какие-то ошибки? Что в логах сервера при клике на ссылку для удаления?

Comment: выполняет тоже действие что и при нажатии для перехода на show achievement. Тоже самое что и эта строчка                          <%=link_to achievement.title, user_achievement_path(@user, achievement)%>

Comment: `method: :delete` реализован средствами JSа, он где-то не подключился. Ошибку надо искать в консоли браузера и в логах рельсового сервера

Answer (score 0):

Убрал с index achievements

```
<%=link_to "Delete", user_achievement_path(@user, achievement), :confirm => "Are you sure?", method: :delete%>
```

и добавил на show achivements

```
    <% if user_signed_in? && @achievement.user == current_user%>
      <%= button_to "Destroy this achievement", @achievement, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-outline-danger'%>
    <% end %>
```

и тогда заработало